# rails render partial collection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a better way to render 3 rows of 3 without calling specifically to the items grouped by 3?

```
<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'thumbnail', collection: @pages[0..2] %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'thumbnail', collection: @pages[3..5] %>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <%= render partial: 'thumbnail', collection: @pages[6..8] %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `in_groups_of` for this:

```
<% @pages.in_groups_of(3) do |group| %>
  <%= render partial: 'thumbnail', collection: group %>
<% end %>
```